# Firefox 33.1 [File > Exit]

Tags: file, firefox, exit

does anybody know how to get back the "Ctrl+Q" Shortcut for newer Firefox Versions to Exit Firefox (close all tabs and WINDOWS)? For me, they stopped working a long time ago. After I looked it up I often read that people complain about it, maybe that's the reason why they left it but for me it was a must have. Already tried to add the shortcut via addons -> didn't work for me :/ [sry for my english]

Thanks in advance for your answer!
-OP

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can't get CTRL+Q back, but what about ALT+F4 (or CTRL+SHIFT+W)?
That closes the Firefox-window.